# Footer always fixed to the bottom of the page bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create footer which is fixed to the bottom of the page and it will show up only when I scroll down to the bottom.
I would like to make it like that because right now is on top of everything. I added a loading page and the footer is visible on that page.

So how do I make the footer so tay always at the bottom of the page. I accept any other suggestions on how to hide it while the loading page is on.

Here is the code of the footer:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-bottom" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div id="footer"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#footer {
    position:fixed;
    background-color:#000;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    display:none;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 100) {
        $("#footer").hide();
    }
    else {
        $("#footer").show();
    }
});
```

[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/5n9h1kz8/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Check with the below link.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HYf7q/32/)

```
    .footerfix{height:4rem;}
footer{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #222;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good tutorial how to keep block at the bottom of the page http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

Basically you just need to add a few styles to your block :

```
.navbar {
   position : absolute;
   bottom : 0;
}
```

All other just depends on other your needs.